# How do I send a mail with attachment?

Tags: emails, 8

I try with this, but no success:

```
$params = [
  'body' => 'My body',
  'subject' => 'My subject',
];

// I check by debug this code and $file get the right file
$file = File::load($myfile_id);

$attachment = [
  'filepath' => $file->getFileUri(),
];

$params['attachment'] = $attachment;

// This send a empty mail, without subject and not body
$send = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('mymodule', 'mykey', 'myuser@gmail.com', 'es', $params);
```

Why doesn't `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail` work?

Then I tried this and it worked fine, but without attachments.

```
$system = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->getInstance(array('module' => 'mymodule', 'key' => 'mykey'));

$file = File::load($myfile_id);

$params = [
  'headers' => [
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal',
  ],
  'to' => 'myuser@gmail.com',
  'body' => 'My body',
  'subject' 'My subject',
  // I try with:
  'attachment' => $file;
  // or
  'attachment' => ['filepath' => $file->getFileUri()];
  // with not success
];

// the mail was sent but without attachment
$send = $system->mail($params);
```

How do I send a mail with attachment on Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7):

Drupal core doesn't support mail attachments/HTML mails.

You need to use an alternative mail implementation, like the [Swift Mailer](https://drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) module.

Also, the reason the first implementation doesn't work is because you need to go through a `hook_mail()` implementation instead. See how core does it.

Comment: Webflo's Drupal 8 port of swiftmailer is now available at https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer

Comment: I was trying to send HTML mails using SimpleNews. I had tried MimeMail, but couldn't get it to work. SwiftMailer is working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1590190) is where there is an example for attaching files using SwiftMailer.